# MAAS and Openstack Network

Tags: networking, juju, maas, openstack

Trying to figure out the best way for openstack and MAAS networks to co-exist.

Assuming MAAS used `10.0.0.0/24` for provisioning of various openstack nodes, once openstack, with quantum, is deployed should `10.0.0.0` be used as management network, external network, both or discarded? Reason for the question being that I ran a deployment where openstack used `10.0.0.0` as its management network, MAAS DHCP and DNS were active; however, I could only access VMs through namespace and was not able to utilize MAAS's DHCP to assign floating IP.

(VMs network was through an internal bridge `10.10.10.10`, and external bridge was using the same interface as MAAS.) Any thoughts or ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 10.0.0.0/24 for both the management network and the external network; in your MAAS configuration, allocate a subset of the IP range for physical server provisioning, and then once OpenStack is deployed, you can configure Neutron to use a different subset of the 10.0.0.0/24 IP range - Neutron will manage this as a separate pool so there is no dependency on floating IP's being allocated by MAAS DHCP.

Make sure that you have two network interfaces cables to 10.0.0.0/24 on the server running the quantum-gateway charm and use 'eth2' as the ext-port configuration.

Comment: Enlightening. Will give it a try. Clarification on the last paragraph, would be appreciated. I take it that the 2 interfaces are meant for MAAS and Quantum subnets. Two questions then: 1- Where should 10.0.0.1 gw be created, i.e., on MAAS server or Quantum node and 2-,I am wondering if I could use a single physical nic, e.g. eth0, then use eth0 for MAAS and use eth0:0 virtual for Quantum? (My network connections are not through a router or switch)